# Why Vue3 is not loading in Laravel 9

Tags: vuejs3, vite, laravel-9

I've installed Laravel 9, and latest version of Vue 3.2.45, It's my first time using Laravel 9 and Vue 3, and I see that the Laravel 9 uses Vite as a module bundler. So I've wanted to do a quick demo just to get me started, but I'm stuck.

I've can't get anything on the screen.

`vite.config.js`:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: ['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'],
            refresh: true,
        }),
    ],
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            '@': '/resources/js',
        },
    },
});
```

`app.js`:

```
import './bootstrap';
import { createApp } from 'vue'

const app = createApp({
    data() {
        return {
            count: 0
        }
    },
    created() {
        alert('test')
    },
})

app.mount('#app')
```

`test.blade.php`:

```
@vite('resources/js/app.js')

<div id="app">
    <button @click="count++">@{{ count }}</button>
</div>
```

Output:

```
<div id="app" data-v-app=""><!----></div>
```

What is happening? The code is running, and I'm getting the alert message, but the app root element is empty.

Comment: If I were you - I would separate the frontend from the backend, i.e. build my Vue.JS single-page application separately from my Laravel REST API. In this way I can later switch the REST API from Laravel to Express.js/Fastify or Python or .NET or something else - and my Vue.JS will still continue to work with no changes.